# Operations with standart input on win32, GIOchanel

Tags: c++, winapi, stdin, glib

Let's assume I got some `GLib` example that checks for `stdin` stream (reads the line from `GIOchannel` bound to it

```
 io_stdin = g_io_channel_unix_new(fileno(stdin));
```

Through `g_io_chanell_read_line())` ,

Get's the data from it and do stuff.

This example was meant to work under *cmd*, I need it to work under *win32 app*.

Obviously I don't have console to print to `stdin`, but I can get this data as string variable as user will type it in my app's input field.

And truly I don't need the console, basically, what important for me - is this standard input stream still exists and working somewhere under the hood of win32 app and therefore can be read through `g_io_chanell_read_line(io_stdin...)`?

Can I pass this string data to it by  `g_io_channel_write(io_stdin...)` and make all this stuff work, or, if not, am I need to make my own stream to bind to `GIOChannel`, and how?

Edit: Some Clarifications:
Few separate processes; in one process user type some data in input field (not win32 field, in fact HTML input field) this process gets this data and can do anything with it - send it to another process, to variable, or anything.

Meanwhile another process in thread, separated from main win32 thread must look for this value, and, as soon, as it gets it - do stuff.

Solution of this "watch for data and do things" must be multi platform and based on Glib.
I thought of sending this data to GIOchannel, cos this was the way it was made in cmd example.

Here's the part, that i'm trying to made an equivalent from:

```
     while (!exit_thread) { 
    GIOStatus s = g_io_channel_read_line (io_stdin, &line, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (s == G_IO_STATUS_NORMAL) {
      gsize sdp_len;

      sdp = (gchar *) g_base64_decode (line, &sdp_len);
      // Parse remote candidate list and set it on the agent
      if (sdp && nice_agent_parse_remote_sdp (agent, sdp) > 0) {
        g_free (sdp);
        g_free (line);
        break;
      } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to parse remote data\n");
        printf("Enter remote data (single line, no wrapping):\n");
        printf("> ");
        fflush (stdout);
      }
      g_free (sdp);
      g_free (line);
    } else if (s == G_IO_STATUS_AGAIN) {
        #if defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)     
    usleep (100000);
    #else
    Sleep (100);
    #endif
    }
  }
```

And now I'm thinking why the hell I can't just make `while(//something//) { if (//string is not empty//) {do stuff and brake or give error} else {run while another iteration}`

Comment: Basically, support is incomplete under windows - the function is one from Linux land. If you just need to read from stdin, you can use cin or scanf or fread with stdin as the file-handle. This sounds like an XY question to me. You'll likely get better answers if you edit your question to state what your ultimate goal is, rather than asking about how to use this particular set of functionality to achieve it. For reference, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I need to know, how can i doo this, using glib. Incomplete? does it mean that i cant use those write and read functions on it? If not - what am i need to create to use those, to insert in `g_io_channel_unix_new(fileno(//something//))`, is it must be some kind of stream or pipe or what?

Comment: Sorry SinnerSmile, I don't understand (as I alluded to) what you're trying to do. Are you simply trying to read input from the user? Explain the problem, rather than the battle with a perceived solution path, as the thread I linked to discusses. Your problem is likely relatively easy to solve - as it stands, your ultimate goal is not clear - the fact that you're unsure if you can use GIOChannel is clear, but what you want to **use** GIOChannel **for** is not.

Comment: Oh, i want to use GIOChannel to read data, that will be stored in string variable, read it as soon, as it gets in that var, and then trigger something.

Comment: Cool, in that case - I'd just abandon the GIOChannel idea on windows and use the long-established methods of getting input from the user. If it's a GUI app, just use an Edit control, along with a call to GetWindowText. If it's a console app, just use cin, scanf, fread etc. If it's a GUI program that uses the GTK framework, just use whatever method is recommended for windows implementations. Given that you're talking about a `string` (a std::string?) I'd probably use cin.getline. See here for an example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: I bit disinformed you about that var, i will add some clearer info to question itself